# Используя include, получить информацию и вывести ее с помощью echo красиво

Tags: include, php, css

Имеется php скрипт вывода информации о сервере, выводит информацию не очень красиво. Помогите, пожалуйста, посредством include вынуть из него информацию и посредством echo красиво ее вывести.

Вот сам [скрипт](http://pastebin.com/PzCbRg38).

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Код удалён.  
"This paste has been removed!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что значит "по средствам `include()`"?
Выложи код ещё раз.

**UPD:**

Если я правильно тебя понял, то тебе служебные функции по добыче информации нужно вынести в файл `info.php` (название от балды), а в файле `view.php` (опять же Балда помог с названием) вывести информацию одной функцией, так?

Файл `view.php` должен быть таким:

```
<?
include 'info.php';
print_r serverInfo('127.0.0.1:443');
```

**UPD 2.0:**

`echo` поможет если будет структурированный возврат функции, иначе ничего ты не получишь.
Я вижу что возвращается массив, значит можно переписать так:

```
<?
include 'info.php'; // Подключаем наши служебные функции
foreach(serverInfo('127.0.0.1:443') as $key => $value) // Пробегаемся по возвращаемым значениям
print $key . ' => ' . $value . "<br />\n";
```

Comment: под*, я про инклюд файла, т.е. скрипт в одном php, а вывод во 2-м вот код: http://pastebin.com/0ErnHr7W

Comment: @hekut146

1. **Пос**редством. Честное слово, я первый раз с таким встречаюсь.
2. Функция getmicrotime идентична вызову `microrime(true)`.
3. Чтобы пользоваться этим эм скриптом, нужно выкинуть последние строки с `print_r`, подключить его и вызывать serverInfo.

Comment: TheDoctor, спасибо большое, примерно то, что я хотел, вы бы не могли, пожалуйста, подсказать коем образом создать переменные определенных параметров, допустим, мне нужно вывести именно статус сервера, включен ли он, т.е. слово on или off и количество человек в онлайне $array['players'], все это дело я хотел бы вынести как раз во view.php, то есть echo 'Статус сервера $status количество игроков $players', как я понимаю, нужно разбить $value, вот только коем образом...

Comment: Как я понял, статус возвращается так: `$array['status']`, значит код такой:

    foreach(serverInfo('127.0.0.1:443') as $key => $value){
     if($key == 'status')
      $status = $value;
     if($key == 'players')
      $players = $value;
    }
    // Some code...
    print "Статус сервера: $status, количество игроков: $players";

Comment: Огромное спасибо, а вы бы не могли подсказать, пожалуйста, последнее, как сделать следующее: вот когда $status => $value = off чтобы он не выводил ", количество игроков: $players"

Comment: Проверять `$value` религия не запрещает, я у Папы спрашивал :)  

    // Получаем $status и $players из примера выше
    if(epmty($status) || $status == 'off'){
     // Тут мы понимаем что статус ложный, можно вывести сообщение что сервер не работает
    }elseif($status == 'on'){
     // Тут на нас снисходит озарение что статус положителен, выводим статистику
    }else{
     // Тут открывается невероятная истина - в статусе не 'on' или 'off', а какая-то левая хрень, можно игнорировать, а можно... Не знаю, воображение включай :)
    }

Comment: Извините, но в php полный ноль, лишь примерно могу понять смысл кода, писать не могу, вы бы не могли написать, коем образом все это должно выглядеть во view.php, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Учи матчасть, студент :)  
Я не могу написать без сорцов твоего проекта, да и написано уже всё.  
Плюс - за тебя никто писать не будет (разве что за плату), тебе хорошо разжевали вопрос, дали ответ, чего ещё нужно?